# C# .NET Core 3.1 SemaphoreSlim with many threads and timeout: how does it work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

In the system I am working at, I have a REST Api available for multiple parallel requests.
In the background, I have a Thrift connection with another tool, allowing maximal 5 threads.
To protect the access to that connection, I am using a SemaphoreSlim object with also a configurable timeout. This is my code:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lockGuard = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 5);
private static int _waitingThreads = 0;

public async Task<Models.OperationStatus> PushItemWithResultAsync<TPushData>(TPushData data, CancellationToken ct)
    where TPushData : Thrift.Protocol.TBase
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _waitingThreads);

    // Use a semaphore to prevent parallel calls.
    if (await _lockGuard.WaitAsync(_millisecondsThriftTimeout, ct))
    {
        _logger.LogDebug($"Push data using {_waitingThreads} threads, but {_lockGuard.CurrentCount} within the semaphore");
        Models.OperationStatus result;
        try
        {
            // push the data to the single Thrift connection.
            result = await PushItemWithResultAsyncLogic(data, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lockGuard.Release();
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _waitingThreads);
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _waitingThreads);
        return GetFailureOperationStatus();
    }   
}
```

I am a bit confused how to use the timeout of the semaphore and the allowed thread.

I first started with new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); to allow only a single connection.
The code behaves as expected: only one call to PushItemWithResultAsyncLogic runs. If too many calls to the methods are coming, they will timeout.

Now, I want to max 5 running PushItemWithResultAsyncLogic in parallel, thus the max allowed thread in the SemaphoreSlim raised to 5.
I expect to still have possible timeout when a lot of external requests are coming.

If 10 parallel calls are received, the timeout of 500ms is still enough to handle all of them.
The _waitingThreads raises up to 10 but _lockGuard.CurrentCount is always 0.
I was expecting to have something moving between 1 and 5...
And most importantly, I don't see the below component to be called up to 5 times.

What is wrong here?

EDIT: short answer: the **initialCount** should be set to 5 as explained below.
So with  new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5), I do have parallel requests AND the timeout playing its job.

Comment: As far as I can see, you are not measuring what you think you are.

Comment: obviously, but how to measure the internal threads used within the semaphore?

Comment: I'm still trying to think of something ... not as easy as it sounds...

Comment: `_lockGuard.CurrentCount` is # threads that can enter the semaphore. When are you getting that value? Also, debug-time values while multithreading are unreliable.

Comment: I think the `_waitingThreads` is misleading. Maybe it's better to log the `SemaphoreSlim.CurrentCount` _before_ the `WaitAsync` _and_ after ... and Kit is right: You could see stale data ...

Comment: What Fildor said. Also, as a point of style, you should have a single try/finally with the `Decrement` in the `finally`.

Comment: @EricBDev actually, I have a question. Why do you need the semaphore at all. Isn't it enough to do the Increment, check the value of the int, and then exit if it's >= your threshold? Well... need to add the timeout in I suppose. Why not just use a throttle?

Comment: The SemaphoreSlim is for me a robust way of protecting my async calls. What would be the alternative?
eventually, the _waitingThreads is useless here, no logic but to log it.

Comment: I still wonder if there is a conflict between the if() with the timeout and the allowed parallel threads.
As it is now, it does change anything if I set SemaphoreSlim(1,5) or SemaphoreSlim(1,1)
When I said current-count always 0, it is on the running system where the service is running within a docker container.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `initialCount` constructor parameter to the same value as `maxCount`. `CurrentCount` goes from `initialCount` towards 0. So, if the `initialCount` is 1 then the first thread sets the `CurrentCount` to zero and prevents other threads from running.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to try next (so trying now), after reading again the
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim
"When the call returns, the count on the semaphore is **decremented**. When a thread requests entry and the count is zero, the thread blocks. As threads release the semaphore by calling the Semaphore.Release or SemaphoreSlim.Release method, blocked threads are allowed to enter"
IMHO, the initalCount is a bit misleading in MS Docs.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It seems now to work a bit more as expected with CurrentCount decreasing from 5 to 0 in my logs, and apparently trying to make concurrent calls.
But now I get OutOfMemoryException from the Thrift library, I am not so sure if it can handle properly parallels requests.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to simulate your scenario with the console app below and added some comments. The Wait method in the semaphore is not used to define a timeout. It is used to block a thread from entering until there is a free slot. Also a distinction needs to be made between allowing a given number of requests to wait and rejecting the others. In the simulation below, 5 is the max number of requests that can be processed *in parallel*. Others will immediately be rejected *until a processing slot is free again*.

As mentioned in the comments, this will not throttle. If you want to change the number of max requests processed in parallel, you need to 1. increase the `maxCount` in Semaphore constructor and 2. `Release(maxCount)` to reset the Semaphore. Or simply call the constructor with `initialCount` = `maxCount`, for ex. `SemaphoreSlim(5, 5)`

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Semaphore
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lockGuard = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 5);
        private static int totalProcessed; // Stats only.

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Reset semaphore by allowing max 5 requests to enter the concurrent section.
            _lockGuard.Release(5); 
            
            var requests = new Task[20];
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending request: " + i);
                var i1 = i;
                requests[i] = Task.Run(() => ProcessRequest(i1));

                // This is the interval between each request.
                // Bigger value means more requests will be processed.
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(requests);

            Console.WriteLine("---");
            Console.WriteLine("Processed requests: " + totalProcessed);
            Console.WriteLine("Rejected requests:  " + (20 - totalProcessed));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task ProcessRequest(int i)
        {
            // If the semaphore is already full, reject the request.
            // This means requests won't get queued.
            if (_lockGuard.CurrentCount == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: CurrentCount == 0 for " + i);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // If this request was allowed to enter the semaphore, wait until a processing slot is free.
                // This decrements CurrentCount.
                _lockGuard.Wait();

                // Once previous request completed (Release()), process the next waiting one.
                await Task.Run(() => {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing request " + i );
                    Thread.Sleep(300); // Simulate request processing time.
                });

                totalProcessed++;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Processing completed: release one slot in the semaphore.
                _lockGuard.Release();

                Console.WriteLine("Releasing " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**
As Kit said in the comments, you don't need a Semaphore to achieve what I understand you're trying to achieve. I assume there are no shared resources in `PushItemWithResultAsyncLogic` code, so what you need is effectively a counter and/or some request queue management if you want to allow some requests to wait.

---

**EDIT**
To process as many requests as possible and have them waiting for a timeout, there is no need to check `CurrentCount`. Simply Wait(x milliseconds) and either request will be processed with lock aquired or it will be rejected and Wait will return false.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Semaphore
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lockGuard = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5);
        private static readonly Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTimeOffset.Now.Ticks);
        private static int totalProcessed; // Stats

        public static void Main()
        {
            var requests = new Task[20];
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var i1 = i;
                requests[i] = Task.Run(() => ProcessRequest(i1));
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(requests);

            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Processed requests: " + totalProcessed);
            Console.WriteLine("Rejected requests:  " + (20 - totalProcessed));
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task ProcessRequest(int i)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(i + " Wait");
                
            // If at the end of the wait no slot is free, reject.
            if (!await _lockGuard.WaitAsync(500))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " Reject");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // Once previous request completed (Release()), process the next waiting one.
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " Process");
                    Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(600, 800)); // Simulate random request processing time.
                    
                });

                totalProcessed++;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Processing completed: release one slot in the semaphore.
                _lockGuard.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the time spend to simulate the scenario.

Comment: As written in the question, my point is to combine the allowed threads with the timeout.
i.e. I do NOT want to reject the request when CurrentCount == 0 but only when CurrentCount == 0 and the time expired. 
So I just replaced your ProcessRequest with my logic above
   if (await _lockGuard.WaitAsync(_millisecondsThriftTimeout, ct))
and it works fine too, e.g with _millisecondsThriftTimeout == 500 (ms). I get only 5 rejected 
requests instead of 11 with your code just started from VS.

Comment: @EricBDev Right. Then I think you don't need CurrentCount. Just wait for the period you want depending on your requests processing time and if after the waiting request still cannot enter the Semaphore, `Wait(x milliseconds)` will return false. Do not `Release()` in this case.